# Querying <div class="name"> in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to follow the guide posted here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe

I am at this point, where I am supposed to get the name of presumably the stock.

## Take out the div of name and get its value

name_box = soup.find(‘h1’, attrs={‘class’: ‘name’})

I suspect I will also have trouble when querying the price. Do I have to replace 'price' with 'priceText__1853e8a5' as found in the html?

## get the index price

price_box = soup.find(‘div’, attrs={‘class’:’price’})

Thanks, this would be a massive help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace `price` with `priceText__1853e8a5` you will get your result, but I suspect that the class name changes dynamically/is dynamically generated (note the number at the end). So to get your result you need something more robust.

You can target tags in BeautifulSoups with CSS selectors (with `select()`/`select_one()` methods. This example will target all `<span>` tags with `class` attribute that begins with `priceText` (`^=` operator - more info about CSS selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('span[class^="priceText"]').text)
```

This prints:

```
2,813.36
```

Comment: I tried to replicate this, to no avail. requests does not exist

Comment: @yottamamba you need to install `requests` library, with `pip install requests` or similar. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/

Comment: I can't seem to install lxml, an error with error code 1 stops me

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to do that.

1. getting the value by appropriate xPath.

> //span[contains(@class, 'priceText__')]

2. Writing regex to find the exact element.

> price_tag = soup.find_all('span', {'class':
>   re.compile(r'priceText__.*?')})

I am not sure with the regex pattern as i am bad in it. Edits are welcome.

Comment: Could you help explain this in more detail? I would like to see code that fully implements what you have written, as I'm afraid just copy-pasting it would not work

Comment: Hi, I just need some clarification, how exactly do I implement this code?